# Stripe in docker can't interact well with my application outside the container

Tags: docker, stripe-payments

I was trying to test **stripe-cli** to replace my old combination of "ngrok+updating the webhook via url". I would really love to be able to use the Docker version, and I managed to install it, login and listen for events via Docker:

```
docker run --rm -it stripe/stripe-cli:latest
docker run -it stripe/stripe-cli login
docker run --rm -it stripe/stripe-cli:latest listen --api-key SECRET_KEY --forward-to DOCKER_IP:1339/stripe
```

But when I try to trigger a payment and the transactions are created, some seconds later these transactions are reported as failing:

```
2022-03-22 20:11:12   --> invoiceitem.created [evt_1KlOOSGgcqHA67le3s8XZ6DT]
...
2022-03-22 20:11:42            [ERROR] Failed to POST: Post "http://172.17.0.1:1339/stripe": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

So it seems Docker can't interact with my application (outside Docker).

What am I missing? Is it any missing parameter?

Comment: If you are trying to forward the request to your application outside of Docker, then shouldn't the IP address not be set to DOCKER_IP?

Comment: @codename_duchess no idea, but that's the closest I got to make it work. I got  DOCKER_IP by running ifconfig -a and copying the IP next to "inet" on the docker0entry (e.g. DOCKER_IP=172.17.0.1). If I don't do that, then I get errors. My app is running at localhost:1339. How should I achieve such an interaction?

Comment: It's not that straightforward. Here's one resource on the topic: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-machine.